# Apache giving me 403 on Virtual Host

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I have been trying to get to grips with Apache in CentOS 7.

I have set up two virtual hosts and created basic index.html pages as follows:

```
/var/www/domainA/public_html/index.html

/var/www/domainB/public_html/index.html
```

Both hosts have permissions as follows:

DomainA:

```
public_html -> jonathan:jonathan
index.html -> root:root
```

DomainB:

```
public_html -> jonathan:jonathan
index.html -> root:root
```

Now, what is happening is DomainA's index.html page is being served up fine, but domain B's index.html gives me a 403 Forbidden.

DomainB's error.log gives me this:

```
AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/DomainB/public_html/index.html
```

Why is this happening? It makes me very sad.

Comment: ¿What filesystem permissions do you have in each directory?

Comment: To expand on motilio's comment: please show us the output of `ls -ld` on all `public_html` and `index.html` files and directories, as well as on `DomainA` and `DomainB`.

Comment: As i was getting the details of the filesystem permissions, i stumbled across the ls -Z command. This highlighted the fact that the working had the `httpd_sys_content_t` context but the non-working domain had something like `user_root_t` context. I set this to be `httpd_sys_content_t` and both domains are now working. Thanks for your help fellas.

Answer (score 3):

The issue turned out not to be file /folder permissions as such, but the security context of the non-working domain.

From my limited understanding, in order for Apache to serve up files, the files / folders need to be configured to run under the `httpd_sys_content_d` context.

My 'mistake' was the non-working domain had been mv'd into the Apache content folder from my Development area and did not have the correct security context so Apache could not serve up the files. This was confirmed by running `ls -Z` on the `public_html` folder and subfolders.

I used `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t public_html/` to set the correct security context and now Apache is serving up everything.

Comment: `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t` Did the trick

Answer (score 0):

`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t <Your_Document_Root_Dir>`

Should do the trick

Comment: Could you please describe what this command does on CentOS?

Comment: Note also that `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t public_html` was described in the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/201716/117549), 3 years ago.

Comment: @Kusalananda chcon changes file context, you may check more at https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux